# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') React

Tags: reactjs

In react I can't run this error please help if anyone knows how to resolve this error.

```
    return (
        <div className="container my-4">
        <h1>News Monkey - Top Headlines</h1>
       
        <div className="row">
        {!this.state.articles.map((element)=>{
        return <div className="col-md-4"  key={element.url}>
       <NewsItem  title={element?element.title.slice(0,45):""}  description={element?element.description.slice(0,88):""} imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
            newsUrl={element.url}/>
            </div>
          })}
```

```
           <div className="container d-flex justify-content-between">
           <button disabled={this.state.page<=1} type="button" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handlePrevClick}>&larr; Previous</button>
           <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={this.handleNextClick}>Next &rarr;</button>
           </div>
           </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: Check if `this.state.articles` exists as well as its type is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing this `!this.state.articles.map((element)=>{`. Putting negation in front of the line `!`. If you would like to know if `state.articles` are an array so that you can render it you should write it like this:
`this.state.articles && this.state.articles.map((element)=>{`